# laravel4 pagination over ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination, laravel

i have a function in my controller that's supposed to return me a paginated set of stuff, i do it exactly same way as in all other controller(**where it works perfectly**) but i get back an **empty object**.
here's function code:

```
public static function getQuotes(){
    $quotes = Quote::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(15);
    $links = $quotes->links();
    return json_encode(array( 'quotes' => $quotes, 'links' => $links ));        
}
```

here's the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: {datagram: datagram},
     success: function(data){
       console.log(data);    //debug
       catEditor.quoteStuff(data);
       typeof data == 'string' ? tools.flash(data) : 0;
     },
     error: function(xhr, status, err) {
       console.log(err.error+' '+xhr.responseText+' '+status);
     }
});
```

Comment: Can yous show what console.log prints out on success?

Answer (score 1):

Can you, for a first step, try with this method :

```
return Response::eloquent(Quote::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(15));
```

Bye

Comment: POST http://localhost:8000/getQuotes 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
undefined {"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Response::eloquent()","file":"C:\\Users\\im\\Desktop\\cms\\app\\controllers\\LayoutController.php","line":53}} error

Comment: It's a laravel 3.X method...Sorry

Answer (score 0):

First, try to return a simple object like this in your getQuotes() method:

```
return Response::json(array('name' => 'Steve', 'state' => 'CA'));
```

If you can get it from your ajax method, you should have a problem with your orm request. Else the problem is in the front.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

```
$quotes = Quote::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(15);
$links = $quotes->links();
return json_encode(array( 'quotes' => $quotes->getCollection()->toArray(), 'links' =>$links ));
```

try this get collection is push instance from object and then convert to array

Answer (score 0):

Paginate returns a Paginator object, not a collection

Answer (score 0):

Just convert $links object to string manualy before json encoding:

```
return json_encode(array( 'quotes' => $quotes, 'links' => (string)$links ));
```

Good luck :)